# Using regular expression in lftp to ignore some strings from file name

Tags: regular-expression, sftp, lftp

Get specific file with name like abc_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.csv from directory using mget.
Example files in a folder:

```
abc_20221202_145911.csv
abc_20221202_145921.csv
abc_20221202_145941.csv
abc_20181202_145941.csv
```

But, I want to ignore hhmmss part. I want to get all files with abc_20221202_*.csv

How to include * in mget.
My code below:

```
File=abc
Date=20221202
Filename=$File$Date"_*".csv
// Assume I have sftp connection established and I am in directory //where files with above naming convention are present. As I can //download the file when hardcoding exact file name during testing
conn='lftp $protocol://$user:$password@$sftp_server -p $port <<DOWNLOAD>/error.log
cd $path
mget $Filename
DOWNLOAD'
```

The script is able to find the file but not able to retrieve it from the server.
But, if I remove * and provide the entire file name abc_20221202_145941.csv it will download the file. Why is * causing issue in retrieving the file

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

Have you tried ftp'ing in manually then executing `mget abc_20221202_*.csv` ? - Does it work outside of the script?

Also, some articles I've read indicate you need to `cd` into the folder first, then run `mget abc_20221202_*.csv`.

Other articles say you need to run mget with the full path, so `mget /full/path/to/files/abc_20221202_*.csv`.